If a space is covered by two closed preregular subsets, is the space preregular?
If a space is covered by two closed preregular subsets, is the space preregular?
A space is preregular, if every two topologically distinguishable points can be separated by open neighborhoods. This is a generalization of Hausdorffness to non-t0 spaces.
Background
The following are related results for Hausdorff spaces:

If a space can be covered by a locally finite cover, where each set is closed, paracompact, and normal, then the space is paracompact and normal. "On spaces having the weak topology with respect to closed coverings, II"
Here normality is assumed to imply Hausdorffness.
Paracompact Hausdorff space is normal
Hence: if a space can be covered by a locally finite cover, where each set is closed, paracompact, and Hausdorff, then the space is paracompact and Hausdorff.


https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000134 for the $R_1$ property

Firstly, I think, "$R_1$" is more common than "preregular". Therefore, I prefer to use $R_1$, if you don't mind.
STEP 1: This holds for $T_2$. More generally, let $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ be a locally finite cover of $X$, such that each $A_i$ is closed and $T_2$. Then $X$ is $T_2$.
PROOF. Let $x, y$ be distinct elements of $X$.
Define $J := \{i \in I: x \in A_i \}$ and
$K := \{i \in I: y \in A_i \}$.
Note that $J$ and $K$ are finite.

For $i \in J \cap K$ there exist $U_i, V_i$ open in $X$, such that
$x \in U_i, y \in V_i, \space U_i \cap V_i \cap A_i = \emptyset$.

$U := \bigcap_{i \in J\cap K} U_i \space\cap\space (X \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I \setminus J} A_i)$

$V := \bigcap_{i \in J\cap K} V_i \space\cap\space (X \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I \setminus K} A_i)$

By local finiteness, $U, V$ are open.
It is easy to see that $x \in U, y \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.
NOTE: In fact, I found this version easier to prove rather than to consider all the different cases in the original question, where the cover consists of only two elements.
STEP 2: Let $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ be a locally finite cover of $X$, such that each $A_i$ is closed and $R_1$. Then $X$ is $R_1$.
PROOF.
Consider the Kolmogorov quotient $KQ(X)$ of $X$ and the canonical map $\lambda: X \rightarrow KQ(X)$.

It is easy to see that $X$ is $R_1$, if and only if $KQ(X)$ is $T_2$.

Moreover, $\lambda$ is open and closed and
$(\lambda(A_i))_{i \in I}$ is a closed, locally finite cover of $KQ(X)$.

Since $\lambda(A_i) = KQ(A_i)$, by the above $\lambda(A_i)$ is $T_2$ for each $i \in I$. Hence, by step 1, $KQ(X)$ is $T_2$ and therefore $X$ is $R_1$.
NOTE: In step 2, the "two element version" is a little bit easier to prove, since one need not show that
$(\lambda(A_i))_{i \in I}$ is locally finite.

Nice. At the start of the proof there is a typo where the second $J$ should be $K$.

@kaba: oh, yes, of course. Thank you!
